# Whitelist IPs for ufw

Tags: firewall, ip, ufw

I have set some rules in ufw to rate limit connections, as such:

```
-A ufw-user-input -p tcp --dport 25 -m state --state NEW -m recent --set
-A ufw-user-input -p tcp --dport 25 -m state --state NEW -m recent --update --seconds 6 --hitcount 12 -j ufw-user-limit
-A ufw-user-input -p tcp --dport 25 -j ufw-user-limit-accept
```

These are in: before.rules

I would like to white list IPs from being subject to these rules. If I run the command:

```
sudo ufw allow from 192.168.0.0/24
```

will this range be white-listed from my rules? Or can this be done another way?

Comment: The only "problem" you would have is in the order of your rules. You will need to put that rule before the others. Iptables follows rules in order.

Comment: Where does the rule: **sudo ufw allow from 192.168.0.0/24** get written to? Feel free to post in the answer, as you have answered the Q.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The "answer" to your question is:

```
sudo ufw insert 1 allow from 192.168.0.0/24
```

This will put the rule first in your rule set.

The order of rules is critical in ufw/iptables as a packet will match the first rule, subsequent rules are (for the purposes of this discussion) ignored.

To see all your rules, in order,

```
sudo ufw status numbered
```

For additional information see

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UFW

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/IptablesHowTo

http://bodhizazen.com/Tutorials/iptables

http://blog.bodhizazen.com/linux/firewall-ubuntu-gufw/

http://blog.bodhizazen.com/linux/firewall-ubuntu-desktops/