# Fail2Ban blocks my IP address due to blocked traffic, how do I stop it from banning me?

Tags: server, firewall, fail2ban

I need to know what program or what specific rule is banning my ip as it happens often when I am programming. It will ban my routers internal IP since I am connecting through the LAN. Then after around 10 minutes it unbans the IP. I need to know what is doing that.

Here is the kernel log,

```
Jul 24 12:40:35 buntubox-001 kernel: [68405.371388] [UFW BLOCK] IN=enp2s0 OUT= MAC=01:00:5e:00:00:01:d8:50:e6:ce:a9:f0:08:00 SRC=0.0.0.0 DST=224.0.0.1 LEN=32 TOS=0x0$

Jul 24 12:42:40 buntubox-001 kernel: [68530.812091] [UFW BLOCK] IN=enp2s0 OUT= MAC=01:00:5e:00:00:01:d8:50:e6:ce:a9:f0:08:00 SRC=0.0.0.0 DST=224.0.0.1 LEN=32 TOS=0x0$

Jul 24 12:44:46 buntubox-001 kernel: [68656.252761] [UFW BLOCK] IN=enp2s0 OUT= MAC=01:00:5e:00:00:01:d8:50:e6:ce:a9:f0:08:00 SRC=0.0.0.0 DST=224.0.0.1 LEN=32 TOS=0x0$

Jul 24 12:46:51 buntubox-001 kernel: [68781.693450] [UFW BLOCK] IN=enp2s0 OUT= MAC=01:00:5e:00:00:01:d8:50:e6:ce:a9:f0:08:00 SRC=0.0.0.0 DST=224.0.0.1 LEN=32 TOS=0x0$

Jul 24 12:48:56 buntubox-001 kernel: [68907.134130] [UFW BLOCK] IN=enp2s0 OUT= MAC=01:00:5e:00:00:01:d8:50:e6:ce:a9:f0:08:00 SRC=0.0.0.0 DST=224.0.0.1 LEN=32 TOS=0x0$

Jul 24 12:51:02 buntubox-001 kernel: [69032.574810] [UFW BLOCK] IN=enp2s0 OUT= MAC=01:00:5e:00:00:01:d8:50:e6:ce:a9:f0:08:00 SRC=0.0.0.0 DST=224.0.0.1 LEN=32 TOS=0x0$

Jul 24 12:53:07 buntubox-001 kernel: [69158.015484] [UFW BLOCK] IN=enp2s0 OUT= MAC=01:00:5e:00:00:01:d8:50:e6:ce:a9:f0:08:00 SRC=0.0.0.0 DST=224.0.0.1 LEN=32 TOS=0x0$

Jul 24 12:55:13 buntubox-001 kernel: [69283.456341] [UFW BLOCK] IN=enp2s0 OUT= MAC=01:00:5e:00:00:01:d8:50:e6:ce:a9:f0:08:00 SRC=0.0.0.0 DST=224.0.0.1 LEN=32 TOS=0x0$

Jul 24 12:57:18 buntubox-001 kernel: [69408.896851] [UFW BLOCK] IN=enp2s0 OUT= MAC=01:00:5e:00:00:01:d8:50:e6:ce:a9:f0:08:00 SRC=0.0.0.0 DST=224.0.0.1 LEN=32 TOS=0x0$

Jul 24 12:59:24 buntubox-001 kernel: [69534.337509] [UFW BLOCK] IN=enp2s0 OUT= MAC=01:00:5e:00:00:01:d8:50:e6:ce:a9:f0:08:00 SRC=0.0.0.0 DST=224.0.0.1 LEN=32 TOS=0x0$

Jul 24 13:01:29 buntubox-001 kernel: [69659.778153] [UFW BLOCK] IN=enp2s0 OUT= MAC=01:00:5e:00:00:01:d8:50:e6:ce:a9:f0:08:00 SRC=0.0.0.0 DST=224.0.0.1 LEN=32 TOS=0x0$

Jul 24 13:03:35 buntubox-001 kernel: [69785.218879] [UFW BLOCK] IN=enp2s0 OUT= MAC=01:00:5e:00:00:01:d8:50:e6:ce:a9:f0:08:00 SRC=0.0.0.0 DST=224.0.0.1 LEN=32 TOS=0x0$

Jul 24 13:05:40 buntubox-001 kernel: [69910.659585] [UFW BLOCK] IN=enp2s0 OUT= MAC=01:00:5e:00:00:01:d8:50:e6:ce:a9:f0:08:00 SRC=0.0.0.0 DST=224.0.0.1 LEN=32 TOS=0x0$

Jul 24 13:07:45 buntubox-001 kernel: [70036.100269] [UFW BLOCK] IN=enp2s0 OUT= MAC=01:00:5e:00:00:01:d8:50:e6:ce:a9:f0:08:00 SRC=0.0.0.0 DST=224.0.0.1 LEN=32 TOS=0x0$

Jul 24 13:09:51 buntubox-001 kernel: [70161.540931] [UFW BLOCK] IN=enp2s0 OUT= MAC=01:00:5e:00:00:01:d8:50:e6:ce:a9:f0:08:00 SRC=0.0.0.0 DST=224.0.0.1 LEN=32 TOS=0x0$

Jul 24 13:11:56 buntubox-001 kernel: [70286.981572] [UFW BLOCK] IN=enp2s0 OUT= MAC=01:00:5e:00:00:01:d8:50:e6:ce:a9:f0:08:00 SRC=0.0.0.0 DST=224.0.0.1 LEN=32 TOS=0x0$

Jul 24 13:14:02 buntubox-001 kernel: [70412.422228] [UFW BLOCK] IN=enp2s0 OUT= MAC=01:00:5e:00:00:01:d8:50:e6:ce:a9:f0:08:00 SRC=0.0.0.0 DST=224.0.0.1 LEN=32 TOS=0x0$

Jul 24 13:16:07 buntubox-001 kernel: [70537.862891] [UFW BLOCK] IN=enp2s0 OUT= MAC=01:00:5e:00:00:01:d8:50:e6:ce:a9:f0:08:00 SRC=0.0.0.0 DST=224.0.0.1 LEN=32 TOS=0x0$

Jul 24 13:18:13 buntubox-001 kernel: [70663.303475] [UFW BLOCK] IN=enp2s0 OUT= MAC=01:00:5e:00:00:01:d8:50:e6:ce:a9:f0:08:00 SRC=0.0.0.0 DST=224.0.0.1 LEN=32 TOS=0x0$

Jul 24 13:20:18 buntubox-001 kernel: [70788.744104] [UFW BLOCK] IN=enp2s0 OUT= MAC=01:00:5e:00:00:01:d8:50:e6:ce:a9:f0:08:00 SRC=0.0.0.0 DST=224.0.0.1 LEN=32 TOS=0x0$
```

Here is the fail2ban log:

```
2017-07-24 06:25:17,215 fail2ban.server [1219]: INFO rollover performed on /var/log/fail2ban.log

2017-07-24 06:25:50,566 fail2ban.filter [1219]: INFO Log rotation detected for /var/log/auth.log

2017-07-24 06:27:31,632 fail2ban.filter [1219]: INFO [sshd] Found 177.129.242.80

2017-07-24 07:42:37,836 fail2ban.filter [1219]: INFO [sshd] Found 171.25.193.131

2017-07-24 07:44:27,693 fail2ban.filter [1219]: INFO [sshd] Found 87.154.220.202

2017-07-24 07:44:27,760 fail2ban.filter [1219]: INFO [sshd] Found 87.154.220.202

2017-07-24 08:17:01,802 fail2ban.filter [1219]: INFO [sshd] Found 119.193.140.164

2017-07-24 09:44:05,257 fail2ban.filter [1219]: INFO [sshd] Found 91.197.232.103

2017-07-24 13:09:25,355 fail2ban.filter [1219]: INFO [sshd] Found 218.68.140.168
```

And finally here is my iptables -L

```
root@buntubox-001:/var/www/html# iptables -L

Chain INPUT (policy DROP)

target prot opt source destination

DROP all -- 192.168.1.1 anywhere

f2b-sshd tcp -- anywhere anywhere multiport dports ssh

ufw-before-logging-input all -- anywhere anywhere

ufw-before-input all -- anywhere anywhere

ufw-after-input all -- anywhere anywhere

ufw-after-logging-input all -- anywhere anywhere

ufw-reject-input all -- anywhere anywhere

ufw-track-input all -- anywhere anywhere

 

Chain FORWARD (policy DROP)

target prot opt source destination

DROP all -- 192.168.1.1 anywhere

ufw-before-logging-forward all -- anywhere anywhere

ufw-before-forward all -- anywhere anywhere

ufw-after-forward all -- anywhere anywhere

ufw-after-logging-forward all -- anywhere anywhere

ufw-reject-forward all -- anywhere anywhere

ufw-track-forward all -- anywhere anywhere

 

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)

target prot opt source destination

ufw-before-logging-output all -- anywhere anywhere

ufw-before-output all -- anywhere anywhere

ufw-after-output all -- anywhere anywhere

ufw-after-logging-output all -- anywhere anywhere

ufw-reject-output all -- anywhere anywhere

ufw-track-output all -- anywhere anywhere

 

Chain f2b-sshd (1 references)

target prot opt source destination

RETURN all -- anywhere anywhere

 

Chain ufw-after-forward (1 references)

target prot opt source destination

 

Chain ufw-after-input (1 references)

target prot opt source destination

ufw-skip-to-policy-input udp -- anywhere anywhere udp dpt:netbios-ns

ufw-skip-to-policy-input udp -- anywhere anywhere udp dpt:netbios-dgm

ufw-skip-to-policy-input tcp -- anywhere anywhere tcp dpt:netbios-ssn

ufw-skip-to-policy-input tcp -- anywhere anywhere tcp dpt:microsoft-ds

ufw-skip-to-policy-input udp -- anywhere anywhere udp dpt:bootps

ufw-skip-to-policy-input udp -- anywhere anywhere udp dpt:bootpc

ufw-skip-to-policy-input all -- anywhere anywhere ADDRTYPE match dst-type BROADCAST

 

Chain ufw-after-logging-forward (1 references)

target prot opt source destination

LOG all -- anywhere anywhere limit: avg 3/min burst 10 LOG level warning prefix "[UFW BLOCK] "

 

Chain ufw-after-logging-input (1 references)

target prot opt source destination

LOG all -- anywhere anywhere limit: avg 3/min burst 10 LOG level warning prefix "[UFW BLOCK] "

 

Chain ufw-after-logging-output (1 references)

target prot opt source destination

 

Chain ufw-after-output (1 references)

target prot opt source destination

 

Chain ufw-before-forward (1 references)

target prot opt source destination

ACCEPT all -- anywhere anywhere ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED

ACCEPT icmp -- anywhere anywhere icmp destination-unreachable

ACCEPT icmp -- anywhere anywhere icmp source-quench

ACCEPT icmp -- anywhere anywhere icmp time-exceeded

ACCEPT icmp -- anywhere anywhere icmp parameter-problem

ACCEPT icmp -- anywhere anywhere icmp echo-request

ufw-user-forward all -- anywhere anywhere

 

Chain ufw-before-input (1 references)

target prot opt source destination

ACCEPT all -- anywhere anywhere

ACCEPT all -- anywhere anywhere ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED

ufw-logging-deny all -- anywhere anywhere ctstate INVALID

DROP all -- anywhere anywhere ctstate INVALID

ACCEPT icmp -- anywhere anywhere icmp destination-unreachable

ACCEPT icmp -- anywhere anywhere icmp source-quench

ACCEPT icmp -- anywhere anywhere icmp time-exceeded

ACCEPT icmp -- anywhere anywhere icmp parameter-problem

ACCEPT icmp -- anywhere anywhere icmp echo-request

ACCEPT udp -- anywhere anywhere udp spt:bootps dpt:bootpc

ufw-not-local all -- anywhere anywhere

ACCEPT udp -- anywhere 224.0.0.251 udp dpt:mdns

ACCEPT udp -- anywhere 239.255.255.250 udp dpt:1900

ufw-user-input all -- anywhere anywhere

 

Chain ufw-before-logging-forward (1 references)

target prot opt source destination

 

Chain ufw-before-logging-input (1 references)

target prot opt source destination

 

Chain ufw-before-logging-output (1 references)

target prot opt source destination

 

Chain ufw-before-output (1 references)

target prot opt source destination

ACCEPT all -- anywhere anywhere

ACCEPT all -- anywhere anywhere ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED

ufw-user-output all -- anywhere anywhere

 

Chain ufw-logging-allow (0 references)

target prot opt source destination

LOG all -- anywhere anywhere limit: avg 3/min burst 10 LOG level warning prefix "[UFW ALLOW] "

 

Chain ufw-logging-deny (2 references)

target prot opt source destination

RETURN all -- anywhere anywhere ctstate INVALID limit: avg 3/min burst 10

LOG all -- anywhere anywhere limit: avg 3/min burst 10 LOG level warning prefix "[UFW BLOCK] "

 

Chain ufw-not-local (1 references)

target prot opt source destination

RETURN all -- anywhere anywhere ADDRTYPE match dst-type LOCAL

RETURN all -- anywhere anywhere ADDRTYPE match dst-type MULTICAST

RETURN all -- anywhere anywhere ADDRTYPE match dst-type BROADCAST

ufw-logging-deny all -- anywhere anywhere limit: avg 3/min burst 10

DROP all -- anywhere anywhere

 

Chain ufw-reject-forward (1 references)

target prot opt source destination

 

Chain ufw-reject-input (1 references)

target prot opt source destination

 

Chain ufw-reject-output (1 references)

target prot opt source destination

 

Chain ufw-skip-to-policy-forward (0 references)

target prot opt source destination

DROP all -- anywhere anywhere

 

Chain ufw-skip-to-policy-input (7 references)

target prot opt source destination

DROP all -- anywhere anywhere

 

Chain ufw-skip-to-policy-output (0 references)

target prot opt source destination

ACCEPT all -- anywhere anywhere

 

Chain ufw-track-forward (1 references)

target prot opt source destination

 

Chain ufw-track-input (1 references)

target prot opt source destination

 

Chain ufw-track-output (1 references)

target prot opt source destination

ACCEPT tcp -- anywhere anywhere ctstate NEW

ACCEPT udp -- anywhere anywhere ctstate NEW

 

Chain ufw-user-forward (1 references)

target prot opt source destination

 

Chain ufw-user-input (1 references)

target prot opt source destination

ACCEPT tcp -- anywhere anywhere tcp dpt:http

ACCEPT udp -- anywhere anywhere udp dpt:http

ACCEPT tcp -- anywhere anywhere tcp dpt:ssh

ACCEPT udp -- anywhere anywhere udp dpt:ssh

ACCEPT tcp -- anywhere anywhere tcp dpt:http /* 'dapp_Apache' */

ACCEPT all -- 192.168.1.1 anywhere

ACCEPT all -- 192.168.1.0/24 anywhere

 

Chain ufw-user-limit (0 references)

target prot opt source destination

LOG all -- anywhere anywhere limit: avg 3/min burst 5 LOG level warning prefix "[UFW LIMIT BLOCK] "

REJECT all -- anywhere anywhere reject-with icmp-port-unreachable

 

Chain ufw-user-limit-accept (0 references)

target prot opt source destination

ACCEPT all -- anywhere anywhere

 

Chain ufw-user-logging-forward (0 references)

target prot opt source destination

 

Chain ufw-user-logging-input (0 references)

target prot opt source destination

 

Chain ufw-user-logging-output (0 references)

target prot opt source destination

 

Chain ufw-user-output (1 references)

target prot opt source destination
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Whitelist IPs for ufw](https://askubuntu.com/questions/525332/whitelist-ips-for-ufw)

Comment: The offending issue based on your kernel / packet drop logs is multicast.  I've answered with that in mind.

Comment: Not a possible duplicate as you can see in iptables I have already whitelisted it.

Answer (score 5):

The core issue here is Multicast (based on your logs).  IGMP stands for "Internet Group Management Protocol", and is a communications protocol used by hosts and adjacent routers on IPv4 networks to establish multicast group memberships.  In most networks this is not necessary and can be safely ignored.

The IP address you're seeing on the 'destination' is the standard multicast address - `224.0.0.1`.  More than likely, your systems are trying to use IGMP, To avoid that, set up a rule *earlier* than your LOG rule that just does a DROP on Multicast packets.  For example:

```
sudo iptables -I INPUT 1 -m pkttype --pkt-type multicast -j DROP
```

This will drop the traffic and *not* trigger log entries - this will therefore mean Fail2Ban doesn't see a log message about it, and therefore you can just 'drop' the traffic and F2B will ignore it as it doesn't know about it from the logs.

(Note that if you use UFW, it may be more difficult to add this type of rule - UFW isn't as versatile as straight-`iptables`)

Note that we have a PSAD box on one client's network, on Ubuntu, and we just silently drop Multicast traffic as we don't really care about IGMP/Multicast traffic on the networks we're monitoring - we only trigger on other traffic that we don't expect (our regular network scanners for determining rogue systems that aren't ours, for example, are whitelisted and "DROP"'d earlier in the ruleset so PSAD and F2B don't see it).

> Related external resources: https://ubuntuforums.org/archive/index.php/t-2231716.html