# Configuration of ufw for one user. Noob

Tags: firewall, ip, subnet

I have several sudo users on Ubuntu 16 PC. ufw is disabled on this PC now. I need to switch ufw on for `sudouser1`. I need to make following config:

1) allow all and any incoming and outgoing connections only from subnet (for example 123.44.*.*) but for all ports and protocols

2a) allow outgoing all and any connections only to specified IP outside subnet

OR

2b) deny ANY connections with specified IP

I try it,  but it seems I am absolutely dummy. Is it possible at all?

## UPDATE:

I need it not for security reasons, as (thanks to  Charles Green) sudo user may just switch off UFW. I need it for a bunch of programms which run on this PC. If it is impossible to do for one user, ok I am ready to do so for all.

## UPDATE2

After my experiments I have:

```
CMT:~$ sudo ufw status

Status: active

To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
Anywhere                   ALLOW       Anywhere                  
Anywhere                   DENY        21.110.11.57              
21.110.11.57               DENY        Anywhere                  
Anywhere                   DENY        21.110.0.0/16             
21.110.0.0/16              DENY        Anywhere                  
Anywhere (v6)              ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
```

But the command:
    netstat -nputw

output:

```
(Not all processes could be identified, non-owned process info
 will not be shown, you would have to be root to see it all.)
Active Internet connections (w/o servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 1.1.1.1:1234       21.110.11.57     ESTABLISHED
```

**What is wrong?**

Comment: I believe that when UFW is present and configured, it operates for all processes, not just a single user.  And since your user has sudo rights, they can bypass or reconfigure UFW...  What re you really trying to accomplish?

Comment: You can filter outbound traffic per user via iptables, but not with ufw. If you are running a server, and wish to limit incoming traffic, you may be able to configure the server or other tools

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Partially From: [Whitelist IPs for ufw](https://askubuntu.com/questions/525332/whitelist-ips-for-ufw)

1) Allow all connection from IP addresses

```
ufw allow from 10.10.0.1/16
```

replace with whatever subnet/IP you want

2b) block incoming traffic from IP

```
ufw deny from 10.10.0.1/16
```

replace with whatever IP/subnet you want

For outgoing traffic, check [using ufw to block outgoing traffic to website](https://askubuntu.com/questions/532305/using-ufw-to-block-outgoing-traffic-to-website)

Simplified:

```
ufw deny out from any to 10.10.0.1
```

or, to allow out

```
ufw allow out from any to 10.10.0.1
```

Comment: Thank you i will try now, but one question - I am bad in subnet masks if i need to restrict only first 2 octets then 10.10.*.* ?

Comment: I also suck at networking, but from my knowledge of wildcards that's worth a shot

Comment: @NerdOfLinux - Nice answer, but these settings are system wide, not per user. See http://jodies.de/ipcalc?host=10.10.0.1&mask1=16&mask2= , so I am guessing 10.10.0.1/16

Comment: OP stated: `I am ready to do so for all.`

Comment: That is a partial quote, the full quote is " If it is impossible to do for one user, ok I am ready to do so for all." It is not possible with ufw, but it is possible with iptables, up to the OP I guess. Change /24 to /16 and I think your answer is good to go.

Comment: No problems that setting are too wide problem that Jetstar still show this connection as established.